# Am I using AC or the schema of specification or nothing special?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a bijection $f$: $C\times C \to A \cup B$ can I define a function $g$:$C \to A$ such that $g(x)=z \iff f(x,y)=z$. Where I am given that there are such elements that satisfy.

I feel that I am **choosing** specific pairs from $f$ to create my new function.

Comment: "A bijection $f$" from where to where?

Comment: Your description of $g$ seems incomplete - where does $y$ come in on the left hand side? Or are you asking whether there must exist some $g$ with the property that if $g(x)=z$ then there is *some* $y$ with $f(x,y)=z$ (noting that this may not uniquely define $g$)?

Comment: @Gae.S. I edited the question, but It doesn't matter cuz the conditions are met. My question is more general.

Comment: @NoahSchweber you can say that all the conditions to define it uniquely are met.My question is more general.

Comment: @yoloexpectz When you ask something to someone else, a precise statement of the question is arguably the only thing that matters. It's not like you have anything better to do anyways.

Comment: @Gae.S. I am concerned that $\iff$ is hiding the use of AC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When only one choice is possible, you don't need to use AC to make it: if I have a formula $R(x,y)$ and a pair of sets $G,H$ such that for each $a\in G$ there is exactly one $b\in H$ with $R(a,b)$, then the function $w:G\rightarrow H$ sending each $a$ to its corresponding $b$ can be constructed with **specification alone** (it's exactly the set $\{\langle a,b\rangle\in G\times H: R(a,b)\}$).

(Remember that functions *are* sets of ordered pairs in set theory.)

---

In fact, we can do a bit better: if we have many different choices we can make but each choice leads to the same "ultimate outcome," we still don't need AC. Specifically, suppose I have a function $f:C\times C\rightarrow A\cup B$ such that:

- for each $c\in C$ there is at least one $c'\in C$ with $f(c,c')$ in $A$ (as opposed to $B$); and
- if $f(c,c')\in A$ and $f(c,c'')\in A$ then $f(c,c')=f(c,c'')$.

*(Note that we're allowing $f(c,c')$ and $f(c,c'')$ to both be in $A$ even if $c'\not=c''$, and we're not requiring $f$ to be bijective.)*

We can *still* use specification alone to whip up the corresponding function $g$: it's exactly the set $$\{\langle x,z\rangle\in C\times A: \exists y\in C(f(x, y)=z\}.$$ We don't need to choose witnesses to the relevant existential facts, we just need to check whether any witness exists at all in each case.